# One to Many relationship / for each in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables Table 1 & Table 2 and the relationship between of them is: one ---> many.

Table 1 --> CaseNumber is the PK | CreatedDate | ModifiedDate

Table 2 --> Id is the PK | CaseNumber is the FK | Age

Table 2 has many records for the same CaseNumber. I would like to query the following:

**for each CaseNumber in Table 2 find the minimum Age**. e.g. Find the minimum age of all records in Table 2.

**Not for a specific CaseNumber** . When I remove the where clause sth strange is happened. I cannot take the minimum for each case number. I am receiving more than row of the same casenumber. It seems that min(age) is not working.

I have some difficulties since the relationship is one to many. How can I handle that?

Sample records are the following:

Table 1 **CaseNumber  CreatedDate  ModifiedDate**

```
        1        12/12/2012 25/12/2012
        2        14/12/2012 15/12/2012
        3        16/12/2012 16/12/2012
        4        17/12/2012 17/12/2012
        5        17/12/2012 25/12/2012
```

Table 2   **Id        CaseNumber     Age**

```
      1  2         23
      2  2         34
      3  2         19
      4  3         25
      5  4         26
      6  4         50
```

I would like to return only 3 rows:

Case number 2 with Age 19

Case number 3 with age 25

Case number 4 with age 26

Comment: can you add ssample records?

Comment: i added some examples

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  CaseNumber, CreatedDate, ModifiedDate, 
        MIN(b.Age) Age
FROM    Table1 a
        INNER JOIN Table2 b
            ON a.CaseNumber = b.CaseNumber
WHERE   a.CaseNumber = 7
GROUP   BY CaseNumber, CreatedDate, ModifiedDate
```

Comment: it works :) I was trying sth similar to that, however I used ORDER BY instead of GROUP BY, thank you very much JW

Comment: Also, If I don't put b.Age in GROUP BY clause I am receiving some duplicates. Why?

Comment: my code should be working as expected, see this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a4aa/1

Comment: it works you are right, however please try to add b.Id in Select clause and GROUP BY clause then it does not work properly, Can't I add some more columns in SELECT clause from Table2 b ?

Comment: so you need the `ID`? this will not give you correct result since you are grouping it including the `ID` from table2 since assuming it is autoincremented, wait i'll update it.

Comment: actually is not only Id, I have some more columns in my real DB that are not auto increment JW

Comment: no, the syntax is generic. but MSSQL supports window functions `:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  B.Id ,B.CaseNumber,MIN(B.Age),A.CreateDate ,
        A.ModifiedDate
FROM    TABLE1 A
        INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.CaseNumber = B.CaseNumber
WHERE   B.CaseNumber = 7
GROUP BY B.Id,B.CaseNumber,A.CreateDate,A.ModifiedDate
```

Comment: If I edit my query by removing the WHERE clause in order to retrieve the minimum age for each caseNumber is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  B.Id ,B.CaseNumber,MIN(B.Age),A.CreateDate ,
        A.ModifiedDate
FROM    TABLE1 A
        INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.CaseNumber = B.CaseNumber
WHERE   B.CaseNumber IN (SELECT CaseNumber from Table2)
GROUP BY B.Id,B.CaseNumber,A.CreateDate,A.ModifiedDate
```

You try this .